# R sockets, reading binary message of arbitrary size

Tags: r, sockets, binary

I am trying to establish R socket binary connection. The idea is that it will do direct data transfer, and the ultimate goal will be using Arrow's binary format. But as of now, I am struggling with simple socket data transfer using R.

My main issue is that I don't know beforehand the size of the sent payload. So, in the server code you will see that it expects a 128-length message. If it is smaller then the connection hangs waiting for rest of the information, if it is bigger it truncates the message to the expected size and ignores the rest.

I've tried using chunks but dynamic reading wasn't working very well. Any tips on how to work with sockets on R? Seems that very little content is available, was trying to replicate something we can find in the [python's socket library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) with `socket.recv()`, `send()`` etc. As I see, I could implement a socket library with Rcpp, but that seems complicated.

I can setup an R socket server

```r
server <- function() {
  while (TRUE) {
    writeLines("Listening...")
    con <- socketConnection(host = "localhost", port = 6011, blocking = TRUE,
                            server = TRUE, open = "r+b")

    
    data <- readBin(con, raw(), 128)
    
    data <- rawToChar(data)
    print(data)

    
    response <- toupper(data)
    writeLines(response, con)
    
    close(con)}
  }


server()
```

and an R socket client

```r
client <- function(){
  while (TRUE) {
    con <- socketConnection(host = "localhost", port = 6011, blocking = TRUE,
                            server = FALSE, open = "r+b")
    f <- file("stdin")
    open(f)
    print("Enter text to be upper-cased, q to quit")
    sendme <- readLines(f, n = 1)
    if (tolower(sendme) == "q") {
      break
    }
    sendme2 <- charToRaw(sendme)
    write_resp <- writeBin(sendme2, con)
    server_resp <- readLines(con, 1)
    print(paste("Your upper-cased text: ", server_resp))
    close(con)
  }
}

client()
```

Comment: I kinda evolved a little bit but still hard to figure things out.
is there something like python's socket.makefile() ?

Comment: For what I was doing, I was able to workaround sending sockets directly with `writeBin`. There was just an type error.
Nonetheless, reading back from socket without a "shutdown" type operation seems hard, because it totally destroys the connection instead of the sending part. 
Not sure how to overcome.